# Uniform convergence polynomial -Stone Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis

A consequence of the Stone Weierstrass theorem, is that for any continuous real function $f$ on a closed bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$, we can find a sequence of real polynomials $f_{n}$ converging uniformly to $f$. I wanted to make sure that the compactness is somewhat important for the theorem to hold, and so I considered the function $f: ]0,1[ \to \mathbb{R}$ $x \to \frac{1}{x}$ which, I think cannot be approximated by polynomials, as it's unbounded near $0$, maybe a little bit intuitive. However, I am lacking intuition for the following fact : can any continuous function $f$, say on $[0, \infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ (closed but not compact) be approximated by a sequence of polynomials ?

Comment: No, compactness is a requirement. Though, I have no counterexample. Waiting for one.

Comment: I think $\exp\colon [0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a counter-example (you won't get a uniform convergence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any bounded non constant function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ is a counterexample: If the degree of the polynomial $p$ is $> 0,$ then $\sup_{[0,\infty)} |f-p| = \infty$ because $|p(x)| \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty.$ The only hope left is a sequence of constant functions, but since $f$ is non constant, $f([0,\infty))$ contains an interval $[a,b],a<b,$ so if $c$ is a constant, then $\sup_{[0,\infty)} |f-c|\ge (b-a)/2.$

Answer (score 4):

You're right, that's a counterexample. Let $f(x)=1/x$. If you had a polynomial $p$ such that $\|p-f\|_\infty < 1$ say, then since $p$ is in fact continuous on $[0,1]$, $p$ is bounded, but $f$ is not, so you get a contradiction.

As for your second question, take $f(x)=x$ sin $\pi x$. Then since any polynomial can only have finitely many roots (in particular, the derivative of $p$ can only have finitely many roots), $f$ cannot be approximated by even a single polynomial $p$ such that $\|p-f\|_\infty < 1$ (or any positive number).

Comment: OP knew that this was a correct example, the question was whether there is a counterexample on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: He wrote that he thought it was a correct example. It doesn't hurt to see a formal argument when you can't think of how to make it... But yes, I realized that a bit too late.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a counterexample by choosing a function that grows faster than any polynomial. For example, you could choose $\exp(x)$.